# How to build a graph of the solution of a second-order differential equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, graph, differential-equations

I need to build a graph for this second order differential equation in MatLab:

φ(t) + (d²φ(t)/dt²) - ((d²φ(t)/dt²) * m * sin(pi) * a) = m * g * sin(pi) * a.

let a = v * t, v = 1, m = 0.1.

0 < t < 1 / v.

I tried this:

```
syms phi(t)
dphi = diff(phi);
d2phi = diff(phi, 2);
g = 9.81;
v = 1;
m = 0.1;
t = linspace(0, 1 / v, 1000);
a = v * t;
ode = phi + d2phi - (d2phi * m * sin(pi) * a) == m * g * sin(pi) * a;
phiSol = dsolve(ode, phi(0) == 0, dphi(0) == 1);
figure
ezplot(ySol);
```

and this also:

```
v = 1;
m = 0.1;
t = linspace(0, 1/v, 1000);
a = v * t;
eqn = @(t, phi) phi + diff(phi, t, 2) - (diff(phi, t, 2) * m * sin(pi) * a) - m * 9.81 * sin(pi) * a;
[~, sol] = ode45(eqn, t, 0);
plot(t, sol);
xlabel('t');
ylabel('φ');
title('Solution of the Differential Equation');
```

But it didn't work at all.

Comment: "It didn't work" is never a problem description (the computer did exactly what you told it to do), [so instead](/help/how-to-ask): explain why you wrote the code that you wrote, what you expected each part to do, and (quite importantly) what you already did to find out at which line(s) things go wrong and what you did to debug that already and what (re)searching you did

Comment: What is `pi`? As it is,`sin(pi)`is zero. `sin(pi*t)` is a function with period 1.

Comment: I believe that there are issues in your equation. But I would recommend you to convert your 2nd order equation into 1st order equation. That will simplify a lot of things for you.